# How to deploy Website and Web Service in one go?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I have created a simple book rating website for my C# project. Now I have a web service which I open in one instance of VS2010 and a website that I open in another instance of VS2010.

Now I need to put it all in a package including a sql create database script so that my instructor can be able to easily install?/deploy the website on his machine.

How would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

First you have make a folder in his application and with database script after that give your instructor and said to him that in database script is run in SQL server and this code run your machine.
If you have to deploye in his machine so go to your IIS and upload the code in his machine.

Comment: So its not possible to have the application be in a OneClick deployment package?

Comment: no, because you have to run sql script in Database sql server

Comment: and without the sql script in a separate folder? I just want to make sure as if that can't happen then I will just supply my 2 projects and the sql script and let him run it himself.

Comment: Okay it is possible but without Sql Script your application nothing So that why Sql script run his sql server database is compulsary.